# Split paragraph into separate lines

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have scraped information from a website that contains many paragraphs. I wish to separate these paragraphs. Below is the current output of texts I'm getting:

```html
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium \n totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore\n veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.\n Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia\n voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui\n dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur\n adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius\n modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?\n Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo\n voluptas nulla pariatur
```

The program recognizes the line breaks between the paragraphs evident in the /n between some of the text in the code above. To insert a line break I am doing the following: print(description).split(\n).

Each time I call the description variable it outputs a prompt list index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
description = description.split("\n")
```

This will split the description variable into a new array on each occurrence of "\n".

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
str = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium \n totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore\n veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.\n Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia\n voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui\n dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur\n adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius\n modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?\n Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo\n voluptas nulla pariatur"

splitStr = []

splitStr = str.split("\n")
for s in splitStr:
   print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your are doing `print(description).split(\n)` instead of `print(description.split("\n"))`

```
string = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium \n totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore\n veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.\n Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia\n voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui\n dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur\n adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius\n modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?\n Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo\n voluptas nulla pariatur"

def split(text):
    lines = text.split("\n")
    return lines
    
print(split(string))
```